# Google SSO with CHIPS in an Iframe

Tags: cookies, iframe, single-sign-on, chips

I have a website that is rendered in an iframe within another website that is not from my domain. I have implemented an SSO Flow with Google where a popup is open, sets the cookies from the backend, closes and then the page in the iframe does the login with those cookies.
When you block third party cookies in Chrome, the flow breaks. This is because the cookies that are set in the popup are not shared with the page in the iframe.
Does anybody know a way to pass those cookies?

We were trying to use CHIPS in this flow, but if you set the partitioned cookies in the popup, the browser says that those cookies are "in another partition" whenever I try to send the request.